# How can I revive my SO question?

Tags: support, old-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

This is probably an already-answered question, but I couldn't find anything similar.

I asked a question on SO, a few days passed and I got a couple of answers and a few comments. I'm not saying that the answers are bad, but they didn't help me. Now, my question isn't getting any new views, so no new answers are being posted.

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions).